# CRUD commands are not refreshed on MySQL Workbench when the springboot app runs on a remote host

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

When i deploy my spring boot application on a remote host, all the `CRUD` commands will **successfully** run on my database, although the changes won't be visible/refreshed from a **Database Client**, **i'm using `MySQL Workbench`** .

Please note that when the application runs on **localhost** all `CRUD` commands are refreshed on `MySQL Workbench`. What i do, is simple to `SELECT * FROM db_schema.table;`.

- On Localhost: I execute a `CRUD` command , and when i refresh the `table` i can see the change
- On Remote Host:  I execute a `CRUD` command , and when i refresh the `table` nothing is being  changed (I'm making sure the command adds an extra row)

This is my database params in springboot `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:port/db_schema?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=db_username
spring.datasource.password=db_password
```

This is the first time that i come across such a weird behavior. I can't figure out what it's causing this.